# How to start service instead of activity via appium?

Tags: android, adb, appium

I am trying to use appium to test one background application which has no interface on android.

I find the following command works:

```
adb shell am startservice -n com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service
```

However, via appium, it tries this command (mentioned: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md, also see Appium logs attached below):

```
adb shell am start -W -n com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service -S
```

This command throws error:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service} does not exist
```

How to make appium use the first command or is there any way to work this around?

appium version: 1.15.0-1

adb version: 1.0.41

Appium logs:

```
[UiAutomator2] Starting 'com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service and waiting for 'com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service'
[ADB] Running 'E:\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 111 shell am start -W -n com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service -S'
[ADB] We tried to start an activity that doesn't exist, retrying with '.com.abc.xxx.Service' activity name
[ADB] Running 'E:\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 111 shell am start -W -n com.abc.xxx/.com.abc.xxx.Service -S'
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://localhost:8271/wd/hub/session/2218b00f-4b2d-42fa-ba41-bc205960cd80] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"2218b00f-4b2d-42fa-ba41-bc205960cd80","value":null}
[ADB] Running 'E:\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 111 shell am force-stop com.abc.xxx'
[Instrumentation] .
[Instrumentation] Time: 5.029
[Instrumentation] 
[Instrumentation] OK (1 test)
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8271 
[ADB] Running 'E:\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 111 forward --remove tcp\:8271'
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1571221550333 (18:25:50 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.abc.xxx' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.abc.xxx' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.com.abc.xxx.Service' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
[W3C]     at ADB.startApp (C:\Users\jzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:153:11)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 24113 ms - 1808
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please read about [security settings](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/security/index.html) that you need to configure for Appium server to make adb commands pass.

Starting with Appium 1.7.2 you can achieve by starting Appium like `appium --relaxed-security`

To execute adb from appium ["mobile: shell"](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) end-point is used:

```
List<String> serviceArgs = Arrays.asList(
"-n",
"com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.Service"
);
Map<String, Object> startServiceCmd = ImmutableMap.of(
"command", "am startservice",
"args", serviceArgs
);
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", startServiceCmd);
```

Not sure about passing `am startservice` as a single command, but you can try different combinations to pass the right object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear. I mean appium will use that adb command to start activity at the beginning of the process. See also: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md